# How to pass a second argument to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

I'm working on a jsp containing a javascript function :

```
function validerSelection(identifiant, page) {
   var form = ObjectId("profilForm");
   form.elements['checkedLogin'].value = "" + identifiant;
   form.elements['pageListe'].value = "" + page;
   form.method.value = '<bean:message key="button.valid"/>';
   window.location = "/STFPresentation/admin/profilUtilisateurSearch.do?method="
        + form.method.value + "&nom=" + identifiant + "&page=" + page;
}
```

The function worked well but I wanted to add a second parameter (called page). "page" is also a variable of my jsp.

I'm calling the javascript function by clicking on a link like this :

```
<a href="javascript:validerSelection('<core:out value="${item.nom}"/>', '<%=numero_page%>')"><core:out value="${item.nom}" /></a>
```

But nothing happens then. Where is my mistake ?

Many thanks

Comment: Is there an error message somewhere?

Comment: what is this `<%=numero_page%>`

Comment: `href` is for an URL to go to, use click event to execute JavaScript when clicked on a link.

Comment: - no error message

- <%=numero_page%> is a variable of my jsp that I'm calling

- href worked well to call the javascript function until I wanted to add another parameter, so I don't think the problem is there

Comment: numero_page is declared like this in my jsp : 

`<%  int numero_page = 0;  %>`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add some escapes:

try this:

```
<a href="javascript:validerSelection('<core:out value=\'${item.nom}\'/>', '<%=numero_page%>')"><core:out value="${item.nom}" /></a>
```

without using escapes, you're creating a wrong sequence of open/close quotes

Comment: thank you for your help but it's not working, error message : "quote expected"

Comment: my fault:

change   \"${item.nom}\"
with   \'${item.nom}\'

Comment: Should not a problem about passing multiple arguments. Try to add a `console.log(identifiant, page);` at the top of your function, you should see both argument correctly passed.

The problems may be a malformed url?
If the two arguments are going to contain single/double quote or other special chars, you need to use the encodeURIComponent() function to quote the content of the params:
`"&nom=" + encodeURIComponent(identifiant) + "&page=" + encodeURIComponent(page);`

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly fixed the problem by adding a hidden value containing my page number

Many thanks for your help